# How can I add instance names to movieclips using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, movieclip

I have a FLA document with a movie clip called "mc_walls".  This movie clip is in the stage over 50 times in the movie and I haven't assigned an instance name each movie clip.

I was wondering if there was a way to add the instance names using some actionscript?

I want all the "mc_walls" to have the name "wall".

I tried this code:

```
mc_wall.name = "wall";
```

**But it returns with this error:**
`1119: Access of possibly undefined property name through a reference with static type Class.`

Help will be great :)

Many Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Do those walls have instance names in your fla ? or is the instance name currently empty for them all ?

Comment: It is currently empty in them all.

Comment: I'm seeing two problems. Firstly, I don't see an advantage to all your MovieClips having the same instance name. Secondly, I don't see an advantage in even having instance names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that there is no instance on the stage with the instance name `mc_wall`, which is why you are getting the undefined property error. If there is not an instance name, then you cannot access it via an instance name, right ?

Next problem you will have though is that you CANNOT modify the name of a Timeline DisplayObject via code. So you will get this error even if you did name it something and then try to change it from that instance name :

`The name property of a Timeline-placed object cannot be modified.`

My thought is that you likely need to learn about arrays and not use the `name` property as the way you manage collections of MovieClips such as your walls.

For instance, if I did have them on the timeline I'd put them inside another MovieClip , basically using it as a container for all my walls and name that instance "wall_container". Then in code I'd do this :

```
var walls:Array = new Array;
for (var index:int = 0;index < wall_container.numChildren;index++)
{
    var wall:MovieClip = wall_container.getChildAt(index) as MovieClip;
    walls.push(wall);
}
```

Now, if I wanted to access an individual wall, I can just go :

```
var wall:MovieClip = walls[5] as MovieClip;
```

or loop through all the walls to collision check or something I can go :

```
for (var index:int= 0;index < walls.length;index++)
{
   var wall:MovieClip = walls[index] as MovieClip;
   wall.x = 500;
   wall.y = 200;
   // do whatever you want to do with that wall

   //check collision ?
   if (player.hitTestObject(wall))
   {
       // handle collision with the wall
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to name MovieClips in the same Scene for control later, this may work with an array:

```
var wall:Array = new Array();

for (var i: int = 0; i < 3; ++i) {

    var mc:Rampart = new Rampart();

    wall[i] = mc;

    mc.y = 100 * (i+1);
    mc.x = 100;

    addChild(mc);
}

wall[0].x = 300;
```